# php implode inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, implode

here is the code

```
$result=mssql_query($query);

while($rows=mssql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
  {
  $subjectcode[] = "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $rows) . "</td></tr>";

  }
```

on my query i have 3 fields, subject1, grade and remarks..

for example the result of the query would be

math 1.55 NULL

now i want to evaluate the field (grade) so that i can insert to the implode part a pass or failed..probably i want to use an in statement inside the loop before the `$subjectcode[]`

Comment: im sorry the while statement is like this----while($rows=mssql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))

  {
  $subjectcode[] = "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $rows) . "</td></tr>";





$counter++;

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to keep the grade and add another column you could do the following (above 40 is a pass)

```
$result=mssql_query($query);

while($rows=mssql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    $rows[] = ($rows[1] > 40) ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
    $subjectcode[] = "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $rows) . "</td></tr>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's an inline if statement.

Comment: ahm what if $rows[1] is a string, how can i convert it to int?

Comment: PHP isn't usually bothered, but if you want to convert it to an int, you can typecast it. $rows[] = ((int)$rows[1] > 40) ? "PASS" : "FAIL";

Comment: what if $rows[1] = "INC" or "incomplete"

Comment: what if there are instances that i have to evaluate the grade in more than 2 conditions

Comment: (int)"INC" will return 0 :) so will produce FAIL with the code I gave you

Comment: Then you would just do an ifelse statement and assign the answer to $rows[] :)

Comment: inc is not a failing grade :) so what can i do to produce a grade INC and not FAIL :) thanks :) ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $rows[1] is grade, and grade 1 failes, grater grades pass:

```
while(...) {
    if ($rows[1] > 1) {
        $rows[1] = "pass";
    } else {
        $rows[1] = "failed";
    }
    $subjectcode[] = "\n" . implode(" ", $rows) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: the implode part should be like this $subjectcode[] = "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $rows) . "</td></tr>";